# Is there a proof that the number $2 \uparrow \uparrow m+3 \uparrow \uparrow n$ is always squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, tetration, prime-factorization

I searched prime factors of the numbers

$$z(m,n) := 2 \uparrow \uparrow m + 3 \uparrow \uparrow n$$

where $m,n\ge1$

Interestingly, z(3,3) is prime, the largest prime I found so far and probably
the largest of the desired form.

So far, I did not find a prime p, such that $p^2$ divides z(m,n)
for some m and n. Since I searched upto about $10^6$, I came to the
conjecture that z(m,n) is always squarefree. Has anyone an idea how this
can be proven ?

Comment: An additional question : Does anyone know a site, where I could suggest a project of searching the prime factors of z(m,n) and publish the prime numbers I already found ?

Comment: Isn't it that it is always congruent $ 3 \pmod 4$ ? (except for trivial cases $m=1$)

Comment: at the additional question: what about the tetration-forum and creating a new thread?